# scaling picture in background, site reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How does this website http://www.rallypoint.com scale their background pictures?

- As I change the size of my browser I can see the height css attribute on the div element changing so I'm assuming it's some kind of javascript working in the background.

[image]

- The javascript function I see in the body is new Slider however I can't find any reference anywhere on the web about this except JQuery UI Slider which does not seem relevant, is that a custom function they wrote?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use the 'background-size' CSS3 attribute:

```
background-size: cover !important;
```

Read more about it: http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Comment: +1 this is the correct answer to "How does RallyPoint.com scale their background image" - the other answers are merely stating how one *can* do it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is certainly more than one way to get the result you want.
I found this the most helpful ...

[Perfect Full Page Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: This is the one that I've used in the past, and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

That is called FLUID layout.... and it is dependent on CSS and not javascript
read a little about boots strap and other CSS properties

By the way here you can see the background-position as 50% in CSS(learn to use chrome development tool)...so that is the HINT